# catkin_make vs catkin_make_isolated

Tags: catkin, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What are non catkin packages? Are all orocos-toolchain related packages non catkin? i.e if i make a package using orocos-toolchain libraries and ros,  than do i have to only use catkin_make_isolated --install command to build package ?

and also what is difference between isolated and non isolated workspace? I was looking at [this](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0134.html) page for this but couldn't get preoperly.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286042/catkin_make-vs-catkin_make_isolated/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2018-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-20**:
You should edit this question or break it into several different ones. You have at least four different questions here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> What are non catkin packages?

Software that does not use the [Catkin](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin) CMake infrastructure in its build scripts, but plain CMake or even something else.

As to the rest of your questions: these are all strictly OROCOS questions. You haven't tagged your question with `orocos`, so the OROCOS devs -- if any of them watch this forum -- may not be aware of your question.

I would recommend to follow @jayess' advice and split up your question into four separate ones and tag them appropriately.

Do please make sure that they haven't already been answered. I expect that especially the catkin ones have received quite some attention in the past already.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2018-03-21**:
hmm ok.  ...